# How to apply multiple transaltion Animation?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to apply multiple translation animation sequentially to my Image View.

But I always ended up having the last animation executed.

I don't why this is happening.
I even add some System Clock sleep call, that's not effective either.

I don't know what I am doing wrong here.

I created a single activity app for making this more simple. In this app, I have only one **Image View**. And I am implementing multiple translation on this **Image View**.

Applied translations are -

translation Left

translation Right

translation Right

translation Left

translation Up

translation Down

translation Down **only this is working**

translation Up

This is my full code for better understanding

```
package com.example.translationanimation;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView arshadImage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        arshadImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewArshad);
    }

    public void imagePressed(View v) {
        translateLeft();
        SystemClock.sleep(2200);
        translateRight();
        SystemClock.sleep(2200);
        translateRight();
        SystemClock.sleep(2200);
        translateLeft();
        SystemClock.sleep(2200);
        translateUp();
        SystemClock.sleep(2200);
        translateDown();
        SystemClock.sleep(2200);
        translateDown();
        SystemClock.sleep(2200);
        translateUp();
    }

    public void translateLeft() {
        arshadImage.animate().translationXBy(1800).setDuration(2000);
    }

    public void translateRight() {
        arshadImage.animate().translationXBy(-1800).setDuration(2000);
    }

    public  void translateUp() {
        arshadImage.animate().translationYBy(1800).setDuration(2000);
    }

    public void translateDown() {
        arshadImage.animate().translationYBy(-1800).setDuration(2000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create an XML resource, like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:pivotX="10%"
    android:pivotY="10%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"/>
```

In code : (I do this, cause it's easy to trigger)

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.shake);
mBinding.image.startAnimation(animation);
```